# Is it possible to toggle the status bar, activity and tab at the same time?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I usually work by hiding the status bar, activity bar, tabs, etc. I follow a procedure similar to this

- Toggle status bar visibility
- Toggle activity bar visibility
- Toggle tab visibility

Is it possible to execute these actions at once?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using an extension like [Toggle](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.toggle) you can toggle multiple settings as a group.  In your keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "F4",
  "command": "toggle",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
    "id": "myZenMode",
    "value": [
        {
          "workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
          "workbench.statusBar.visible": true,
          "workbench.editor.showTabs": true
        },
        {
          "workbench.activityBar.visible": false,
           "workbench.statusBar.visible": false,
           "workbench.editor.showTabs": false
        }
      ]
   }
}
```

If you are hiding most of the workbench elements, have you looked at `Zen Mode`? Under `view/Appearance`.